# Current splitting in nA,pA range till 100 kHz frequencies

Tags: current, circuit-design

This relates to my previous question of current splitting. [Current splitter/divider in nA/pA range possibilities](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/425445/current-splitter-divider-in-na-pa-range-possibilities)

I read about some circuits on current copying (current conveyor). However, the circuits operate less than around 10 kHz.

- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263076351_Current_Mode_Techniques_for_Sub-pico-Ampere_Circuit_Design_Special_Issue_on_Current_Mode_Circuit_Techniques
- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/42ae/6752d1f2656aeddcf34519702c289dc8d653.pdf

But my requirement is to copy currents at a high frequencies (100kHz).

Therefore, I wanted to know if circuit in [Current splitter/divider in nA/pA range possibilities](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/425445/current-splitter-divider-in-na-pa-range-possibilities) 's answer or any current copying circuit would work at high frequencies with a high linearity? or is it something impossible?

Comment: Who knows what your FET parameters are?  Why not simulate it  , maybe>? http://tinyurl.com/y6j8uy89

Comment: Is this inside an integrated circuit or a board-level design?

Comment: @EdgarBrown This is to be inside an IC.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Well, simulation is possible with a normal nmos current mirror, but at high frequencies (kHz in this case), there are many parasitic effects, which I hope is not easy to simulate. Last answer by analogsystemsrf revealed that this structure could work till 50 Hz.

Comment: Yes I would expect 1/Req*Cstray to be low. f  Even though input and output impedances are low.

Comment: "...would work at high frequencies with a high linearity?" - define 'high'.

Comment: This kind of sounds like a potential XY question. Would you mind elaborating what exactly the purpose of the current splitter is? (I'm also just curious :) )

Comment: @Platytude It is for comparing the output of two current sensors.